# Solving CORS issues in Moovweb

Tags: cors, moovweb, tritium

I facing one issue while working on moovweb tritium project. The site I'm proxing is using external domain (CORS) to perform some operation.

Due to this, "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http:// (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '')." error occured.

I've added the external url in the host_map variable in config.json file. Even after I'm getting this error.

I also tried with changing the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to proxy url in the /scripts/response_main.ts file, but it also failed.

As I know, my site is using external url to add some js and css resources that is responsible to perform some ajax operations.

My question is :

1. How can be fix this CORS issue ?
2. Can we modify some urls in external js file to proxy url using tritium that may be causing this issue.

Any help will welcome.

Excuse typos.

Thanks.